# XSLT subtraction

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a problem with the following XSL code.

It's really simple subtraction, but it does something strange. I know I can just use `format-number`, but can someone explain to me why I get `0.4299999999999997` instead of the expected `0.43`?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:value-of select="36.98 - 36.55"></xsl:value-of>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Found a answer.  
Warning With some XSLT processors, the use of decimal numbers may introduce a tiny error. For example, the "3.2 - 4" in this example comes out as "-.7999999999999998" on some processors. While being off by .0000000000000002 isn't much, being off at all shows that math is not XSLT's strong point.

Comment: This is not about xslt. This is about how floating point numbers are represented in computers in general. You basically can get similar results in almost any language when using float/double types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Read about floating - point arithmetic**:

**http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point**